# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null "ERRO"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou tentando abrir um site externo através de uma página que criei clicando com um botão, mais não consigo referenciar o documento que criei, segue o código abaixo, tentei diversas vezes e não consegui, qualquer auxílio é válido, muito obrigado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Principal</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 
 <script src="\\fswcorp\ceic\ssoa\gaacc\System\JQuery\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="\\fswcorp\ceic\ssoa\gaacc\System\jQueryMask\dist\jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
 <script src="\\fswcorp\ceic\ssoa\gaacc\System\jQueryUI\jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dateBegin").mask('00/00/0000');
  $("#dateEnd").mask('00/00/0000');
 
  $("#buttonDownloadBRScan").click(function(){
   $windowopen = window.open();
   $windowopen.location.href = "https://www.fdibr.com.br/autenticacao/autenticacao/login";
   $test = $windowopen.document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML = "7478704";
  })
 });
   
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="dataInput">
  <label id="labelDateBegin">Data Inicial</label>
  <input id="dateBegin" type="date"/>
  <label id="labelDateEnd">Data Final</label>
  <input id="dateEnd" type="date"/>
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <button id="buttonDownload">Download</button>
 <button id="buttonDownloadBRScan">Download BRScan</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML` - não vejo nenhuma tag com id `usuario` no html

Comment: vc tem controle sobre a página que está sendo aberta no window.open e ela é do mesmo domínio? Se não, pode esquecer.

Comment: este html que consta é da minha página, estou automatizando o processo de carregar outra pagina e preencher automaticamente o id usuario da outra pagina que é um link externo. mais não estou conseguindo manipular o elemento da outra página através do meu javascript.

Comment: @FelipeDiasDeSouza, não seria o caso de armazenar esse valor em um cookie?

Comment: o problema não é armazenar a variável e sim obter o controle da $windowopen, uma vez que ela morre quando o click() acaba, e após o click() acabar não consigo trabalhar com essa variável novamente pois o escopo dela acabou.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa incluir um `onload` para saber quando a página aberta com `window.open` foi carregada e assim alterar o elemento dela. Mas também é preciso passar algum parâmetro ao `window.open`. Você pode colocar `null`.

> Pra variar, não funciona no IE.

Altere a parte do seu código para o abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dateBegin").mask('00/00/0000');
   $("#dateEnd").mask('00/00/0000');
   $("#buttonDownloadBRScan").click(function(){
      $windowopen = window.open(null);
      $windowopen.location.href = "https://www.fdibr.com.br/autenticacao/autenticacao/login";

      $($windowopen).on("load", function(){
         $($windowopen.document)
         .find("#usuario")
         .html("7478704");
      });
   });
});
```

[**Exemplo funcional**](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t2.php)

Comment: realizei a sua idéia, entretanto não consigo inputar a informação no elemento usuário que está na outra página, ele carrega a pagina, mais não atribui o valor no elemento.=/

Comment: O unico jeito então seria passar a informaçao via URL. Para isso eh necessario incluir um codigo tb na pagina aberta.

Comment: não consigo passar informação via URL pois a pagina não é minha, é de um terceiro.

Comment: Acho que não tem como, o navegador bloqueia acesso ao conteúdo da página de terceiros.